# Why is "!!" considered bad form in Perl?

Tags: perl, boolean, type-conversion

During a recent job interview process, I submitted some sample Perl code which used the so-called "secret" `!!` [operator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Bang_bang).  Later, when discussing the code, one of the interviewers asked me why I chose to use that, and indicated that it was considered bad form. He didn't elaborate as to why.

My team and I have been using this operator for years, without ever realizing it was considered "bad form."

Does the "bang bang" operator have side-effects or other unexpected behavior? Why is it, or might it be, considered "bad form" by some? Is there an idiomatic alternative?

Below are a few examples where I would have considered `!!` acceptable and/or desirable.

1. The actual code in the coding exercise, which is an example of adding booleans:

   ```
   while (my $line = <$F>) {
       # snip
       exists $counts{lines} and $counts{lines} += !! chomp $line;
   }
   ```
2. Using a boolean value as a hash key (clearly a simplified example):

   ```
   sub foo {
       my ($input) = @_;
       my %responses = ( '' => "False", 1 => "True" );
       return $responses{ !! $input };
   }
   ```
3. Using a boolean in a bitwise operation, or even `pack()`:

   ```
   sub foo {
       my ( $a, $b, $c ) = @_;
       my $result = !!$a + (!! $b)<<1 + (!! $c)<<2;
       return $result;
   }
   ```
4. You need to do a typecast for use by an external library/process, such as a database, which only considers certain values to be truthy:

   ```
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (flag,value) VALUES (?,?)")
   $sth->execute("i_haz_cheeseburger", !! $cheeseburger_string)
   ```

Comment: It might end up being opinion based and thus OT. After all - code idioms you like/dislike are opinion, and code styles are more policy. However - I've given a reason I would call it 'bad form', and think as a collection of _possible reasons_ why it might (or might not) be, that's not so bad.

Comment: `sub Bool { shift ? 1 : "" }` should be same as `sub Bool { !!shift }`

Comment: What's the alternative? Even the ternary is a better alternative; it at least says what the outcome will be: `sub doublebang($){return $_[0]?1:''}` .

Comment: Still having a bit of trouble with that last example. I'm really having difficult with the notion of quite why you'd use a boolean state, and then do arithmetic operations with it.

Comment: @Сухой27, It's not the same. `sub Bool { shift ? 1 : "" }` is not the same as `sub Bool { !!shift }`. Try `Bool(0)+0` when warnings are on.

Comment: `Many of those "operators" are not suitable for production code, because they are obscure to the uninitiated` -- perlsecret

Comment: Ok, to keep them internally marked as PVNV, !0 and !1 should be used.

Comment: `Bang bang` operator. I love it. I will forever call it this.

Comment: While I'm not fond of using treating booleans as numbers (as in your example), I wouldn't have a problem using `!!f()` to normalize a boolean value (that could be a long string) into a simple value (except to question whether it's actually needed at all).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your `!!` takes advantage of two obscure things in Perl: The specific values that `!` returns, and that one of the possible values is dualvar (a scalar containing both a string and a number). Using `!!` to compound these behaviors is admittedly pithy. While its pithiness can be a huge plus, it can also be a rather big minus. Don't use features that result in a project mandating that "the use of Perl is forbidden on this project."

There are lots of alternatives to `$count += !! (some_expression)` to count occurrences of truthy values of that expression. One is the ternary, `$count += (some_expression) ? 1 : 0`. That too is a bit obscure. There is a nice compact way to do what you want, which is to use the post-if:

```
$x++ if some_expression;
```

This says exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Agree about using post-if, but a ternary operator is not "obscure" nor obtuse

Answer (score 65):

I'd call it 'bad form' because it simply isn't necessary. You don't need to boolean convert in Perl. And so at best it's redundant, and at worst it's an obfuscation.

While there are some really nice tricks you can use in Perl, one of the biggest problems with the language (perceptually at least) is that it's rather prone to "write once" code.

After all - why do you ever need to 'double-negate' a scalar to get a boolean, when you can just test the scalar?

```
my $state = !! 'some_string';
if ( $state ) { print "It was true\n" };
```

Or:

```
if ( 'some_string' ) { print "It was true\n" };
```

And it's true - you can write some horrifically unintelligible Perl code thanks to "secret" operators, punctuation-based variables, etc. And it'll work fine - for example - I still consider this a masterpiece: [3-D Stereogram, Self replicating source](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=118799)

But it isn't 'good code'. For 'real world' usage, your code needs to be clear, intelligible and easy to troubleshoot.

Regarding alternatives;

```
while (my $line = <$F>) {
    # snip
    exists $counts{lines} and $counts{lines} += !! chomp $line;
}
```

This is ... counting how often you've successfully `chomp`ed a line I think? So basically it just counts numbers of lines in your input.

For that, I'd be thinking 'use `$.`'. Unless I've missed something profound about your code?

> "What if it's not chomp?"

Well, OK. How about:

```
 $counts{lines}++ if foo();
```

For this:

```
sub foo {
    my ($input) = @_;
    my %responses = ( "" => "False", 1 => "True" );
    return $responses{ !! $input };
}
```

I'd be writing that as:

```
sub foo {
    my ($input) = @_;
    return $input ? "True" : "False";
}
```

For the last condition - packing flags into a byte:

```
sub flags {
    my @boolean_flags = @_;
    my $flags = 0;
    for ( @boolean_flags ) {
        $flags<<=1;
        $flags++ if $_;
    }
    return $flags;
}

print flags ( 1, 1, 1 );
```

Or perhaps if you are doing something like that - taking a leaf from how [`Fcntl`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Fcntl.html) does it by defining values to add based on position, so you're not having to worry about the positional arguments problem:

> You can request that the flock() constants (LOCK_SH, LOCK_EX, LOCK_NB and LOCK_UN) be provided by using the tag `:flock`.

And then you can:

```
flock ( $fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB );
```

They're defined bitwise, so they 'add' via the `or` operator - but that means it's an idempotent operation, where setting `LOCK_NB` twice wouldn't be.

For example,

```
 LOCK_UN = 8
 LOCK_NB = 4
 LOCK_EX = 2
 LOCK_SH = 1
```

If we expand the question to the less subjective:

> I'm asking for the reasons to avoid !!

- Perl evaluates "truth" of variables, so there's not really much need for an actual logical boolean.
- Conditional statements are clearer than their equivalent boolean algebra. `if ( $somecondition ) { $result++ }` is clearer than `$result += !! $somecondition`.
- It's on a secret operator list *because* it's obscure. Your future maintenance programmers may not appreciate that.
- `!!1` is `1`, `!!0` is `dualvar('', 0)`. While that's quite flexible, it can surprise, especially since most people don't even know what a dualvar is, much less that `!` returns one. If you use a ternary, it's explicit what values you get:`$value ? 1 : 0`

Comment: I have to say - I can't think of any scenarios where I've needed an "actual boolean". Evaluating the truthiness of a scalar has always done the trick. The odd edge case of tri-state `true`/`false`/`undef` being perhaps the only exception, and there you've got `defined` and `//`.

Comment: OK. Sorry, going to need you to expand on "adding two boolean values". I mean, I've seen it used in the context of a boolean `or` operation. (As C/C++ does). But you've already got boolean `or` (and `||` for logical  and `|` for bitwise) (Or `xor` for logical or `^` for bitwise)

Comment: @Flimzy - If you want to convert some value to 0 or 1, your `!!` trick doesn't do the trick. What  `!!` does is to convert a truthy value to 1, a non-truthy value to the empty string. While 1 is the minimal truthy value in perl, 0 is not the minimal non-truthy value in perl. That would go to the empty string. Your `!!` trick doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: The very last paragraph might be the most important one.

Comment: " You don't need to boolean convert in Perl." -- One obvious reason for returning a proper boolean is that you might not want to leak implementation details in a public API.

Comment: Whilst I agree generally, I'm also pretty sure that 'just' injecting `!!$var` into your API output is good form either.

Comment: @Sobrique: So what alternative do you advocate?

Comment: Conditionally returning an explicit value. Your API is going to have to apply a transform anyway - stringification if not conversion to JSON/XML or similar.

Answer (score 18):

The whole question is somewhat subjective, so I'd like to give an opinion that differs from the other answers posted so far. I wouldn't consider double negation bad form in general, but I'd try to avoid it if there's a more readable alternative. Regarding your examples:

1. Use something like `$count++ if $condition`.
2. Truth values as hash keys? That's simply evil. At least, it's surprising for anyone who has to maintain your code.
3. Here the use of `!!` is justified.
4. Here I'd use the ternary operator. It isn't really clear how `execute` behaves when passed a dualvar.

Another situation where it's completely OK to use `!!` is when casting certain values to Boolean, for example in a return statement. Something like:

```
# Returns true or false.
sub has_item {
    my $self = shift;
    return !!$self->{blessed_ref};
}
```

Most programmers should know the `!!` idiom from statically typed languages where it's often used as a cast to bool. If that's what you want to do and there's no danger of unwanted side-effects, go with the double negation.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about the return case you mention at the end. That's another one I have used before.

Comment: For that last case, I would be thinking of simply using "defined" so you aren't tripped over by present but false values.

Comment: @Sobrique: unless you want to treat defined but false values as false.

Comment: Then you can just return the value, because any conditional you're testing it in... works exactly the same.

Comment: @Sobrique: It's generally considered bad form to return a data type other than that which is expected by the caller. If the function tests truthiness, it should return a boolean. Especially if you consider the "public API" argument made in other comments above. I don't think "don't convert to boolean" is a valid answer to this question.

Comment: If we were talking about a strongly typed language, I would agree. Perl isn't.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it's not so bad for code only you see.

However, your fellow developer might see it one day fixing a bug in your code, and stumbles upon this. There are two options

1. He thinks you made a mistake and removes one `!`, invalidating your code
2. He thinks this is just software rot, and removes both `!!` without a second thought. After refactoring some other code, it suddenly hangs on... a type mismatch?

Either way, it will waste the time of future developers, unless they happen to be familiar with it. Intelligible code is never for yourself (well, it could help), but for any others who will ever see your code.

Comment: In college days I gave my friend a hard time for nesting 2 level deep ternary operators in one line and calling it "compact and cool".  I said "it is stupid and impossible to maintain because I have to spend 30 minutes to manually trace something."

Comment: As wise man once said.  Debugging is twice as hard as coding. If you are as clever as you can be when you write it,  how will you ever debug it?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the job, it's bad form for a lot of **business and interview** reasons as well...

1. when working on a team project, or any other code where many other developers could be working on it, don't obfuscate (or follow company policy)
2. going of what sanchises said, it will cause more work, and does not clearly display the intentions of the code.
3. it's simply unnecessary, and as discussed above - it sounds like there is at least one scenario where the result would not work - hence a bug.
4. showing uses of obscure coding in an interview, when there is an easier and clearer way to do it doesn't look favorably in an interview.
5. an interview is the place where you want to show that you are a team player, not that you are going to whip out weird crap that nobody else understands (unless it happens to be the answer to an unsolved issue of course)

p.s. it would have been in good form to ask the interviewer why he considered it "bad form".  A handy interview followup tip, would be to send him a thank you and ask him why he considers it "bad form"

Comment: +1 for following up to show the interviewer you can have a reasonable discussion about it and respect their opinions.

Answer (score -1):

one of my most frequently deployed use case for `!! x` would be upfront special handler for `0` or `1` after accepting numeric input

*e.g.* in a `pow()` type of subroutine, there are definite time savings for special handling of both the `base` to be exponentiated, and also the `exponent` itself -

---

- `exponent == 0` := directly return numeric `1`
- `exponent == 1` := directly return the `base`

---

- `base == 1` := just directly return the `base` of numeric `1`
- `base == 0` :=

  —  `exponent < 0` —> return `+inf` (some say `-inf`)

  —  `( default )` —> return a `1/0` indicator of whether `exponent` is also zero

---

So instead of having to check `base == 0 or base == 1`, I'd do something like :

```
 if ( base == !! base ) { 

    . . . 

 } else if ( expn == !! expn ) { 

    . . . 
 }
```

Since only numeric 0 or 1 could get themselves back after a double logical negate.

*I suppose one could also do* `if ( base == base * base )` *to capture `0` or `1` without using something like a case/switch statement, but that could be much slower if we're dealing with gigantic bigints*